Problem with sending POST/GET Request at the same time - Nuxt 3
Now I'm looking to load the last projects of a user from the database by sending his name and receiving all the last projects related to this user. For some reason, I keep getting "Uncaught (in promise) FetchError: [POST] "/api/lastProject": 500 Internal Server Error" everytime I try to do this.
the frontend code:
let lastProjects = ref(null);
async function getLastProjects () {
  const { response } = await $fetch('/api/lastProject'
    , {
    method: 'post',
    body: {
      identity: data._value.name 
    },
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  }
  )

  console.log('response: ', response)

     if (!response) {
       throw new Error('Response is undefined');
    }

  lastProjects.value = response;
  return lastProjects;
}

onMounted(async () => {
    await getLastProjects()
});

backend "/api/lastProject.post.ts":
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  try {
  const identity = await readBody(event);

  const url = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
if(!url) {
  throw createError({
    status: 400,
    message: "there is an error with the url"
  });
}

const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
  await client.connect();
  const db = client.db();
  const collection = db.collection('topicalMapsData');

  const users = await collection.findOne({ identity });

  if (!users) {
    throw new Error('User not found');
  }

  return users;
  } catch(err){
    throw new Error('Error: ', err);
  }
  finally {
    await client.close()
  }
});

So what's exactly wrong with this code?
I tried adding .get/.post to the file name and doing some edits to the request code structure but it didn't work out.

Have you tried logging the errors in the server inside the catch?  That will give you more details and include the logged errors in your question.

I believe there is a typo mistake in   new MongoClient(uri... it should be  new MongoClient(url...
I think you should also specify the DB in  const db = client.db(); like const db = client.db('myDb');
